# Cut out shape (triangle) from div and show background behind

Tags: html, css

I am trying to cut a triangle out of a div and show the background as it is behind the div... I would not have thought this to be possible, but you SO pros continue to surprise me here so I thought it was worth a shot :-)

This is what I would like to achieve (sorry for the faint image):

[image: Triangle cut out]

***<sub>Please do not answer this question with a 3 column solution or something similar, I am more than capable of achieving this that way... I simply want to know if there are any cool CSS tricks out there that can achieve this with as a few graphics, if not no graphics, as possible?</sub>***

Comment: See the question [How does this CSS triangle shape work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work) The idea is to use an element with height and width set to 0, and then use borders to create the shape. See the code example in that question.

Comment: I am not trying to create a triangle! I am trying to cut a triangle out of a div!

Comment: If the question is a duplicate please flag the original question accordingly. An answer should be self contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could seperate your triangle from the rectangle and go with something like this:

```
<div id="rectangle"><div id="mask"></div></div>



#rectangle{width:300px; height:120px; position:relative; margin-top:100px; background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(30,87,153,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}

#rectangle:after{content:" "; position:absolute; width:0px; height:0px; top:0; left:100px;border:1px solid white; border-color:transparent white transparent white; border-width:0px 50px 50px 50px;}

#mask{position:absolute; left:0; width:100px; height:50px; background:white;}
#mask:after{position:absolute; content:" "; left:200px; width:100px; background:white; height:50px; }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4a8/2/).

Comment: I am afraid this is not what I am looking for as it just creates a triangle with the same background as the one behind... I need the triangle to be transparent so that the background shows through no matter what it is. For instance, if the background behind was a gradient (which it is) then this gradient would continue through the triangle... Thanks anyway

Comment: check this again: http://jsfiddle.net/Qs4a8/4/

Comment: This looks great, need to test it thoroughly before I accept though... Is it browser compatible? Thanks so much +1

Comment: Just to make this a little more complicated... Is it possible to change the borders of the triangle from colours to images? The background of the center rectangle is also a gradient so the borders must be images...

Comment: The only way that i could think to add a border image to that triangle would be by placing a squre div with desired border behind your triangle and rotate it by 45deg.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to fake it, with some fantasy and some little tricks:

- Use `border-radius` to cut out a transparent corner of the div;
- Use `::before` (or `::after`) pseudo element to create a big triangle of the same background-color of the div;
- Use `z-index` to put the triangle *over* the background div but *under* the *content* of the div;
- Use a `transparent` container with the same size of your div to contain it, and apply `overflow: hidden` to cut the exceeding parts of the triangle;

  et voilà!

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/e2Umv/

And no, I didn't know it was possible, I just love challenges and tricky questions :)

HTML

```
<div class="someText" >
    this text is partially visible;<br/>
    this text is partially visible;<br/>
    this text is partially visible;<br/>
    this text is partially visible;<br/>
    this text is partially visible;<br/>
</div>
<div class="underneathContainer">    
    <div class="cutout">Hello cut out div</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.someText{    
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;    
    top: 0;
}


.underneathContainer{
    margin: 20px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 260px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);    
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cutout{    
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;    
    background: silver;
    padding: 30px;    
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border-top-left-radius:30%;    
}
.cutout:before{    
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -44px;
    left: -30px;
    border-width: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) silver silver rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 for your effort! Thank you, but are you able to do this with a triangle in the center like in my image?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of that applies here would be the [image mask](http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking). You'd probably have to lay an element on top of another to have content over the mask.

The support for image-masks is not ubiquitous (only webkit at present I believe) but that will probably change over time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not the solution I am looking for. I guess it doesnt exist, although that doesnt surprise me... Thanks anyway