# wrap text around an image or shape from both sides

Tags: html, css, svg, text

How can I have a text wrapping around an arbitrarily positioned image or shape within a single block of text?

[image]

<sub>image is property of https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/</sub>

---

*Note that I am not looking for a solution that involves separate columns of text such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52867877/985454) which exploits left/right `float`s with `shape-outside`.*
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this moment, this behaviour is **not supported**, however, there is a draft for it.

More reading:
https://css-tricks.com/exclusions-will-hopefully-be-like-more-powerful-grid-friendly-floats/
https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-exclusions-1/

> ## CSS Exclusions Module Level 1
>
> ### Editor’s Draft, 16 January 2020
>
> *CSS Exclusions define arbitrary areas around which inline content can flow.*
>
> [image]

---

## CSS Shapes Module Level 2

Note that there also was a `shape-inside` property, which would have been possible to use as a workaround with a proper polygon, but its support was removed and implementation postponed until https://drafts.csswg.org/css-shapes-2/. So right now, it is only possible to use `shape-outside` with a `float`-ing element.

[image]
[image]
<sub>images property of https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-shapes/</sub>

> The initial Shapes specification included a property `shape-inside` for creating shapes inside an element. This property, along with the possibility of creating shapes on **non-floated** elements, has been moved to level 2 of the specification. As the `shape-inside` property was initially in Level 1 of the specification, you may find tutorials on the web detailing both properties.
>   ~ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Shapes/Overview_of_CSS_Shapes#Future_CSS_Shapes_Features)