# Is there a way to center a div between to columns without it covering them?

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I need to put the  between the two columns without them being covered from it. I've tried with float but it obviously covers the text below.

```
h2 {
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0 25%; 
    margin-top: 25%;
   }
```

The result should be like the one on the image. I've added the code here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/aschimmenti/pen/eYdxOvW)
Thank you in advance! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hu2F.png)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60654583/8620333

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wrapping two columns of text around an image/shape from both sides html css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867877/wrapping-two-columns-of-text-around-an-image-shape-from-both-sides-html-css)

Answer (score 0):

with `float` and some `margin`/`clear`, with known sizes you can manage this inside a column CSS layout :

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;}
 
article {
  column-count:2;
  height:500px;
  width:1200px;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:justify;
}
article header  {  
  float:right;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  padding:1em;
  margin-left:0.5em;
  margin-right:-160px;
  background:gray;
  text-align:center;
}
article:before {
  content:'';
  float:left;
  width:0;
  height:440px;
}
article > b  { 
  float:left;
  clear:left;
  height:200px;
  width:150px;
  float:left;
}
p {margin:0 1em 1em;}
```

```html
<article>
  <header class="none">
      <h1>some title text to lay over here and see what we can do about it to set it in the middle</h1>
      <a href>Written by Lorem Hardy</a>
  </header>
  <b class="none"><!-- push it next col--></b>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</article>
```

**But useless since it can break anytime.**

---

A javascript approach could help retrieve the size needed once the document is loaded. the use of `var()`  CSS that can easily be updated/reset  and reused inside the CSS styles , then  `class` to remove after sizes are taken via js can reduce the code and prepare it ahead.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  let article = document.querySelector("article");
  let header = document.querySelector("article>header:first-of-type");
  let b = document.querySelector("article>b:first-of-type");
  let Hspacer = article.offsetHeight + "px";
  header.classList.toggle("none");/* let header take its style and width */
  let headerH = header.offsetHeight + "px";/* now how tall is it ? */
  article.style.setProperty("--Hspacer", Hspacer);
  article.style.setProperty("--headerH", headerH);
  b.classList.toggle("none");/* finalize the spacer standing in column 2 */
};
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  --Hspacer: ;
  /*to be updated via js */
  --headerH: ;
  /*to be updated via js */
  --headerW: 260px;
  /* init header 's width */
}

article {
  column-count: 2;
  height: var(--Hspacer);
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: justify;
}

article header:not([class=none]) {
  float: right;
  width: var(--headerW);
  height: var(--headerH);
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
  margin-right: calc( ( var(--headerW) / 2)* -1);
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

article:before {
  content: '';
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: var(--Hspacer);
}

article>b:not([class=none]) {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: var(--headerH);
  width: calc( var(--headerW) / 2);
  float: left;
}

header h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0.75em;
}

p {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <header class="none">
    <h1>some title text to lay over here and see what we can do about it to set it in the middle</h1>
    <a href>Written by Lorem Hardy</a>
  </header>
  <b class="none"><!-- push it next col--></b>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</article>
```

Inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyYzGYX

if your column container is partially fluid, you may need to update the `--Hspacer` value  : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dypaydo