# How to create a perfectly round circle filled with text of variable sizes in CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a react.js app and need to dynamically make a text of variable size look like its held perfectly in a circle (pic attached).

I tried by creating little divs on each side of the text to make it look like a circle but it was not good enough and too complex to implement for texts of different sizes[image]

Comment: please don't repeat the same question after one month (we have a good memory ..)

Answer (score 2):

Not the answer you look for but some hints about shape-outside :
it requires to know the length of your text and size your boxes into squares.

image or gradient can be used to push text from area where they are drawn.

example :

```css
div:not([class]) {
  width: 24em;
  min-height: 24em;
  /* see me
  border:solid;
  border-radius:100%;  
  */
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: justify;
}

div[class]:before {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  content: '';
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(circle at bottom right, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  float: left;
}

div[class][id]:before {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top right, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(circle at top right, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  float: left;
}

div[class]:after,
div[class][id]:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  float: right;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, transparent 70%, black 70%);
}

div[class][id]:after {
  content: '';
  float: right;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, transparent 70%, black 70%);
  shape-outside: radial-gradient(circle at top left, transparent 70%, black 70%);
}


/* extra */

body {
  font-family: 'Times New Roman';
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.28em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-flow: dense;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  margin: auto;
}

body> :nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 2 / span 2;
  color: tomato
}

body> :nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 3 / span 2;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
  color: green
}

body> :nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 2 / span 2;
  grid-column: 5 / span 2;
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div class="shape" id></div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div class="shape" id></div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <div class="shape" id></div>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>
</div>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside The `shape-outside` CSS property defines a shape—which may be non-rectangular—around which adjacent inline content should wrap. By default, inline content wraps around its margin box; shape-outside provides a way to customize this wrapping, making it possible to wrap text around complex objects rather than simple boxes.

Browser support for [shape-outside](https://caniuse.com/#search=shape-outside)

Comment: Seems a good solution for me and It's a perfect answer for the canonical duplicate (https://stackoverflow.com/q/19909266/8620333).